# Multiple grouping and count in Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

Suppose I have this table, which I'm loading into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
name id ...
n1   1
n1   2
n2   3
n2   4
n2   5
...
```

Now, I want to retrieve the count of ids for each unique name.

In SQL, I'd do (correct me if wrong)

```
SELECT name, id, COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY name, id;
```

How would I achieve the same with Pandas?
This:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'id'])['name', 'id'].count()
```

is giving me the separate counts of names and ids.

Comment: In SQL you need `GROUP BY name, id` at the end of your query.

Comment: And I don't know pandas , but in addition to what jarlh said, i guess you shouldn't group by count, only name and id.

Comment: @jarlh sorry that was my forgetting to write it, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on 'name' and then call [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) on 'id' this will return the count of values:

```
In [38]:
df.groupby('name')['id'].count()

Out[38]:
name
n1    2
n2    3
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

What you're effectively doing is grouping on both 'name' and 'id' so the unique values are the combination of both columns, you're asking for the count of ids for each name which is not the same thing

```
In [41]:
df.groupby(['name','id'])['name','id'].count()

Out[41]:
         name  id
name id          
n1   1      1   1
     2      1   1
n2   3      1   1
     4      1   1
     5      1   1
```